# How to prevent ScintillaNET control from auto scrolling?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scintillanet

I am using a ScintillaNET control in my C# Winforms application. I am trying to implement an auto-tag feature that will auto-complete the tag before, for example, when a user types `<html>`, auto-complete feature will trigger and insert `</html>`.

I'm using the ScintillaNET `CharAdded` function for this implementation:

```
if (caretPos != 0)
        {
            //If the characters before the caret are "ml>" (last three chars from "<html>")
            if (TextArea.Text[caretPos - 1] == '>' && TextArea.Text[caretPos - 2] == 'l' && TextArea.Text[caretPos - 3] == 'm')
            {
                TextArea.Text = TextArea.Text.Insert(caretPos, "</html>");
                TextArea.SelectionStart = caretPos + 0;
                TextArea.Selections.First();
                TextArea.ScrollCaret();
            }
        }
```

## Problem

My problem is, the Scintilla control keeps scrolling either all the way up or all the way down. I thought the `ScrollCaret()` function would work, but it keeps happening. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've struggled with this problem too. Thought it was a [bug](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/issues/128). Even the solutions given on the Github issues page didn't help. But then i found out that if you insert a text using:

```
TextArea.Text = TextArea.Text.Insert(caretPos, "");
```

Then that itself will be the problem. ScintillaNET already has a function for `Text.Insert`. Using `InsertText` will prevent the control from scrolling.

### EDIT

Found the problem also issued [here](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4402a264-30df-4930-8888-c181b67c813d/stopping-1st2nd-scintilla-net-control-from-scrolling-when-text-is-changed?forum=Offtopic)